# Convert string of numbers to different divs with classes. Either Jquery or Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, html

So I have a string of numbers echo'ed from a database.
This string of numbers would look something like:

```
var numbers = "12,156,4,198,759"
```

I want this string to be printed in to different divs such as

```
<div class="div-12"></div>
<div class="div-156"></div>
<div class="div-4"></div>
<div class="div-198"></div>
<div class="div-759"></div>
```

This string could create a massive number of divs, even up to a few thousand.

This could be either done with Ajax or pure client side Jquery. However, Ajax is preferred.

I honestly have no idea how I would go about doing this.
I do not quite some Ajax, so you do not have to go in to detail.

Please help me out :)

Comment: `var htmlChunk = '<div class="' + numbers.replace(/,/g, '"></div>\n<div class="') + '"></div>';`

Comment: That actually worked, awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got your data back from your ajax call as a comma-separated list of number, you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RrA3u/1/

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,99";

var list = numbers.split(",");

$.each(list, function(index, value){
    $("#container").append("<div>").class("div-" + value).text("div " + value));
});
```

Comment: You left the 'div-' part out. Class names cannot start with a digit.

Comment: Good catch, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript, you could do something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACHsV/2):

```
function createDiv(element, index, array) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "div-" + element;
    div.innerHTML = "class div-" + element;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}

var numbers = "12,156,4,198,759";
var number_list = numbers.split(",");
number_list.forEach(createDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

For best performance use fragments:

```
var fragement = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (i in list) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "div-" + list[i];
    div.innerHTML = list[i];
    fragement.appendChild(div);
}
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(fragement);
```

Results on an array of 1000 numbers:

- **Using jQuery:** 73ms
- **Using fragements:** 8ms

http://jsfiddle.net/rotev/EnNYM/2/